# issue with application paths when adding it to a website in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a website in IIS7 wish i've added an application to it my problem reside in the application paths when I try to click on a link in the application it's always redirect me to the default page of the website even though when I open the application alone without merging it every path work right so we were obligated to change every path of the application for them to work fine . my question is :

1. Is adding an application to a website the best solution for merging two websites ?
2. Is there any other way that don't actually need to change all the application paths ?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I open the application alone without merging it"? Could you expand on how you are doing that?

Comment: i mean when the application is stand alone separated from the parent website

Comment: @Sora, can we look at your website?  Do you have a url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About first question**

If you would like to host 2 application on one IIS you have two choices:

1. Add application to website (as you did) - this option is good if your webconfigs are 100% compatible, because root webconfig will also change settings in child application
2. Create Reverse proxy - it is much safer because both asp.net applications are completely separate. You can look on this setup tutorial http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)

**About second question**

If you decide to use child application,  unfortunately you do not have any other option to "rewrite" all your links in your code. My suggestion is to create a function which will automatically add prefix to external links, and store base link for other site it configuration. I did such project with success.

If you decide to use reverse proxy and have "easy" separate links, you could setup reverse proxy to do work for you. For example all links started with "A" goes to application 1, rest to application 2. You could write really complicate rules, using regular expressions.